# Logitech K360 alternative with Bluetooth

Tags: keyboards

I've used the [Logitech K360 Compact Wireless](https://www.logitech.com/en-ca/products/keyboards/k360-compact-wireless.920-004088.html) keyboard for a couple of years and love it for mobile use with my laptop.

It uses the infamous Logitech Unifying Receiver.

But my employer recently replaced our laptops and now I have only USB-C slots. I could use an adapter, but I don't like the idea of this double-length protuberance while I take the laptop in and out of my bag and other movements. And constant removal and insertion is [a minor pain](https://www.google.com/search?q=first-world%20problems). This is the only thing that needs to be USB'd into my laptop, so if I could replace it with Bluetooth I'd love to.

What's a good equivalent to the K360 that's Bluetooth? I don't care about brand at all, but it should:

1. Have a numpad and the associated keys (home, end).
2. Have media keys if possible, but not essential.
3. Be no more than 400mm, the size of my laptop bag. The K360 is 380mm and barely fits. I tried a 450mm and it does not fit. The MX Mechanical felt great but is too big. The mini version does not have a numpad.<sup>1</sup>

Alternatively, if some electrical engineer can think of a way to replace the connection chip in this thing with a Bluetooth one... :)

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> "Change your laptop bag?" If I absolutely have to, but I'd rather just pick a keyboard that suits it. This bag is a lovely compact size.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [**Logitech K780**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01GV6HP0E) keyboard.

- Has a numpad (but no home/end keys)
- Media keys only part of the function key row
- Size is the same as the **K360** (a bit thinner)
- Has Bluetooth connection (as well as optional Unifying receiver connection)
- Price is substantially more

[image]

---

Two other possible options that do have Home/End keys:

- The [**Microsoft Designer Bluetooth Desktop Keyboard and Mouse**](https://amzn.to/3D8Ylm7) (has Home/End in coulmn between num pad and main keyboard)
- The [**Dell Multi-Device Wireless Keyboard and Mouse Combo - KM7120W**](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-multi-device-wireless-keyboard-and-mouse-combo-km7120w/apd/580-aisy/pc-accessories) (has Home/End keys on the top function row)

Comment: A great candidate, but the home/end keys are a dealbreaker. More inconvenient to lose those than to fiddle with the USB adapter.

Comment: Probably not much help... But there is 'some' Home/End key, as function buttons on the numpad's 1 and 7 keys.

Comment: Added two more options

Comment: Nice. The Microsoft one might work. 430mm — could possibly stretch into the bag. Now I just need to find somewhere I can try it out to be sure the keys don't feel terrible...

Comment: Where did you get to 430 mm? Length is listed as 15.32"/389.2 mm

Comment: Oh! Even better. I confused it with another I was looking at.